# Clausula INSERT ignorada na procedure

Tags: pl-sql

Estou com um problema que já pendo a acreditar ser falta de fé.

Tenho uma proc que realiza uma série de **inserts** e **updates**. Ela passa pelo primeiro **insert** e pelo primeiro **update** e executa o que é proposto. Nos demais **inserts**, aparentemente a clausula **insert** é ignorada na **proc**. O **select** referente ao **insert** em questão retorna dados, se eu pegar o bloco e executar separadamente em outra janela ele efetivamente faz o **insert** e, colocando um **DBMS_OUTPUT** na **proc** logo abaixo de cada **insert**, é possível ver que ele passa por lá normalmente, só não faz o que é proposto.

Em resumo, ele executa os dois primeiros comandos e os demais ele ignora, mesmo passando por eles.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser isso?

Como exemplo, segue um fragmento da proc e a saída do DBMS:

--O comando anterior executa um insert que efetivamente popula a tabela de pedidos corretamente com os parâmetros passados
--Após, temos esse insert seguido de outros inserts em outras tabelas, mas que são semelhantes
--Ao final de cada insert, coloquei um DBMS_OUTPUT, que retorna a mensagem de ter passado por lá
--Pegando cada insert e executando separadamente, eles funcionam, mas na proc não

```
begin
 INSERT INTO BANCO.PED_COMPL_PEDIDO   (
         EMPRESA,
          PEDIDO,
          DAT_HOR_INCLUSAO,
          USUARIO_INCLUSAO,
          PORTADOR,
          TIP_PORTADOR,
          FORMA_PAGTO,
          FINALIDADE_USO,
          TIP_DESC,
          EMISSAO_PEDIDO,
          PROCESSO_EXPORT,
          EMPRESA_VENDA
          )
select    
         'FF' ,--EMPRESA
          pedidos.num_pedido, --PEDIDO
          sysdate, --DAT_HOR_INCLUSAO
          'user ', --USUARIO_INCLUSAO
          '', --PORTADOR
          '', --TIP_PORTADOR
          '', --FORMA_PAGTO
          '', --FINALIDADE_USO
          '', --TIP_DESC
          '', --EMISSAO_PEDIDO
          '', --PROCESSO_EXPORT
          '' --EMPRESA_VENDA
          from BANCO.pedidos
          where pedidos.cod_empresa= 'FF'
          and pedidos.dat_pedido= vDataEmissao
          and pedidos.NUM_PEDIDO_CLI = idEntrega
          and pedidos.num_pedido not in (select pedido from BANCO.PED_COMPL_PEDIDO
                           where usuario_inclusao='clientUser '
                           and DAT_HOR_INCLUSAO >=(sysdate-60));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Passou pela PED_COMPL_PEDIDO');

commit;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vDataEmissao || ' Data emissão');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(idEntrega || ' id Entrega');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------');

end;
```

---

A saída do DBMS foi essa:

Passou pela PED_COMPL_PEDIDO

30/10/17 Data emissão
27583545 id Entrega

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com a sua `procedure` para que fique mais fácil para ajudarmos.

Comment: Se possível coloque o trecho de codigo e tente aprofundar mais no que você está tentando fazer e como acha?

Comment: Pessoal, fiz uma edição com um fragmento dela. Obrigado!